# How can maven dependency with 'runtime' scope can be useful (used)?

Tags: java, maven

Since *runtime scope* for maven dependency makes it impossible to "see" this dependency from parent project, how can it be useful?

*Example parent maven project pom:*

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example-dependency</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope?
</dependency>
...
```

As i understand, not `main` entry function, nor any classes in parent project can reference anything in `example-dependency`.

According to the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html):

> This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for
> compilation, but is for execution. Maven includes a dependency with
> this scope in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile
> classpath.

But this doesn't explain exactly, how such scope can be useful. Can something somehow be executed inside such bundled dependency on it's own, without being referenced by the parent app?

What is the point of bundling such dependency into the jar?

Comment: @tgdavies no, this does not answer the question, because it does not provide a specific example, how api is affected by the implementation. As i understant, the api can have some generic classes, implementation can extend them and then what? The root app doesn't see those extending classes anyway.

Comment: The answers provide the examples of avoiding accidental dependencies on the implementation of an API, and JDBC drivers. You say " The root app doesn't see those extending classes anyway" -- it does at *runtime*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you know there will be an implementation at runtime environment, you don't want to refer any specific `Class` of any implementation at development environment, `runtime` scope could help.

> As i understant, the api can have some generic classes, implementation can extend them and then what? The root app doesn't see those extending classes anyway

**Java SPI (Service Provider Interface)** could scan implementations in your environment (classpath) dynamically and easilly. Database drivers are common examples. (`java.sql.Driver` -> MySQL / Postgres / any database driver)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you project is builded as - A.jar
and this A.jar is dependent on another library - B.jar

Both the jars are dependent on log4j.jar for logging purpose.

In this case you will be adding log4j as runtime dependency to B.jar's pom so that it will compile without any issues.
And when A.jar is builded from its pom the log4j and B.jar will be included.

This will also help to avoid runtime method conflict.